# Error during uploading mern stack project into heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

[image]

In Procfile:

```
web: node Backend/server.js
```

In `package.json` of backend, I am using post build for react app. its saying cannot find module `/app/backend/server.js`.

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Backend/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node backend/server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon backend/server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false && npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend"
   },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.28.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.10",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13",
    "stripe": "^8.197.0",
    "validator": "^13.6.0"
  }
}
```

My project is laid out like this:

- `Backend/`
- `frontend/`
- `Procfile`
- `package-lock.json`
- `package.json`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Well, do you _have_ a `backend/server.js`? We only know what you tell us, we can't see your machine. (Note that `Backend/server.js`, as listed in your `package.json`, is different from `backend/server.js`.)

Comment: https://github.com/sumit-khatry/react-ecommerce

Comment: I have added github link for folder strucuture and others

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should be self-contained. I asked a specific question. In the future, please answer questions clearly and [edit] any relevant information directly into your question. We shouldn't have to go off-site to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your `start` script tries to run `node backend/server.js`, but your file is actually at `Backend/server.js`. Heroku's filesystem is case-sensitive. You can use either option, but you must be consistent.

Here is one solution. Rename your directory:

```
git mv Backend backend
```

And update your `Procfile`:

```
web: node backend/server.js
```

Then commit and redeploy.